# Data pulling from one spread sheet to other google spread sheet and new data row to be added in the last row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a master data sheet which is updated been updated daily bases. from the master data sheet, cases will be assigned to my staff. I am doing this using Query function with condition as staff name. from there data will be pulled to individual staff sheet where they will update about the complete status of the case in new columns. Here I am facing some issues

1. If cases like 1 to 10 cases are initiated. If only 2, 6, 8 are initiated to staff A for certain reasons then later if Staff A is assigned with 3,4. Then rows are aligning like 2,3,6,8 instead of 2,6,8,3,4 periodically. Can I get new data row in last row.
2. If staff A is assigned with case 3 but later we thought of assigning it to staff B then data is been reshuffled in updating sheet. Can we over come these situations.

Comment: can you attach a link or images to describe the original data and the data after the query?

Comment: @Theza Please do not encourage Users on leaving images. Please read [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Welcome. Please read [ask] and how to [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311).

Comment: @marikamitsos thank you will share accordingly. test sheet

Comment: @theze [Master data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pcxjGjzjNtAWy4WzMEAFFwzGZu_wyDgbYOr8B3NnBYY/edit#gid=0), [Staff](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pcxjGjzjNtAWy4WzMEAFFwzGZu_wyDgbYOr8B3NnBYY/edit#gid=0) once please check

Comment: This is just your data. Where is the expected results? Sorry I don't understand.